# Does overriden method in a class automatically called when a object is created

Tags: android, sqlite

If we use overriden method in myclass then these methods is called automatic when an object of class is created?

Also what is the use of helper.getwritabledatabase

Comment: I don't know what "helper.getwritabledatabase" (and I think I'm not alone). Your first sentence also makes no sense. You should clarify (maybe post some code to "illustrate")

Comment: The super class implementation of a method is not called by default, if you want to call it you have to do super.methodName.